# How can I redirect my grep to a txt file, located in another directory?

Tags: linux, grep

```
grep -n '[0-9]' test.txt > output.txt
```

I would like to redirect the above grep results on to a new file (not yet created, `output2.txt`), which needs to be located in another directory than the directory of `test.txt`. For example, maybe at  `nothome/labs/output2.txt`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the absolute path to your output, like this:

```
grep -n '[0-9]' test.txt > /path/to/output/output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

From your posting I guess you might want to create the output path first:

```
OUTPUT_PATH=/path/to/output
mkdir -p ${OUTPUT_PATH}
grep -n '[0-9]' test.txt > ${OUTPUT_PATH}/output.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment.


The path was already there, I was just not sure whether the grep  command will create an output2.txt on its own or I would have had to create it separately on my own. 


Another query if I may, How can I extract a string of words from text file using grep.
I am trying  grep -n '[life,death]' test.txt - in order to list the line numbers along with words [life and death] that may occur in the file test.txt. But i guess the syntax that i am using is wrong.

Comment: update - grep -no "life,death" test.txt  - gives me the line number and the text where the exact string "life,death" is present in the text file. I want to grep the whole line that contains this phrase. How do I do that ?
Also what will be the syntax be if I want to find separate occurrence of both the words separately.
Thanks.